# How can I get a session ID?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

In Selenium for Java I can call `RemoteWebDriver.getSessionId()` to get the GUID associated with my browser session.

How can I get the session ID in Playwright?

I've looked at the members of any seemingly relevant object (`Browser`, `Page`, `Context`, etc.) and I've searched, and I can't find anything.

Maybe there isn't a session ID, but I feel like there must be because our browser host for automation associates Playwright browser sessions with a GUID just like it does for Selenium browser sessions.

Comment: what is the use case where you want to reuse the GUID? I don't think there is such an option to retrieve it, but maybe there is an already existing functionality that would provide a solution for your original problem.

Comment: I'm using Element34's Selenium Box for testing, and I want to call their API to update sessions as pass or fail based on test results.  To do that, I need to pass in a session ID, which at least for Selenium is a GUID.  Selenium Box shows GUIDs for Playwright tests too, so those must come from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DEBUG=pw:browser* to get the sessionID details.

https://playwright.dev/docs/selenium-grid#detailed-logs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34988287)